# Deleting and updating a database c#

Tags: c#, sql, button, textbox

I have problem with trying to figure out how to update and delete data inside a database using textboxes and a button.

My insert code is:

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {



            string query = "insert into Prodaja values (@Prodajalec,@Prodajalna,@Kupec,@Vozilo,@DatumNakupa)";

            using (connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
            {

                connection.Open();
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Prodajalec", textBoxProdajalec.Text);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Prodajalna", textBoxProdajalna.Text);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Kupec", textBoxKupec.Text);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Vozilo", textBoxVozilo.Text);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DatumNakupa", textBoxDatumNakupa.Text);
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();



            }

            MessageBox.Show("Uspešno dodano");               
            this.prodajaTableAdapter.Fill(this.prodajaDataSet.Prodaja);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

I tried a couple of different methods but they didnt really work out. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What output/error message do you receive?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be mixing up the syntax of your insert vs update statement.

```
Insert statement:
insert into #table (col1,col2) values ('col1','col2')

Update statement 
Update #table set col1 = 'col1', col2 = 'col2' where id = 'id'
```

EDIT: Delete Syntax

```
Delete from #table where id = 'id'
```

Comment: Yea i fixed that now I copied the wrong code. The code ive posted works but I dont know how to update and delete from this base.

Comment: You should just be able to use my example syntax above for the update. Just adding a where for the specific record based on some or other unique field. Will update the answer with the delete syntax.